# Using THREE from forge-viewer/node_modules/@types/three causes compiler error

Tags: angular, typescript, autodesk-viewer

I need to use `Viewer.setThemingColor()` method that requires a parameter of type `THREE.Vector4`.

I am working with Angular 9 and I have installed `@types/forge-viewer` that also includes a definition for three at `forge-viewer/node_modules/@types/three`.

Visual Studio Code picks up the definition of `THREE.Vector4` and inserts `import * as THREE from 'forge-viewer/node_modules/@types/three'` but the `ng build` command throws an error:

`Can't resolve 'forge-viewer/node_modules/@types/three'.`

I have tried to add three to both `tsconfig.app.json` (types) and `tsconfig.json` (typeRoots) in many variations but that does not help.

Additional installing of `@types/three` and importing from 'three' will fix the compiler error but it creates duplicate definitions in different locations and Visual Studio Code will only automatically see the location from `forge-viewer forge-viewer/node_modules/@types/three` and not `three`.

What is the problem her and how to fix it?

Comment: There is an additional side effect when installing `@types/three`: there are two different copies of `three.js` loaded in a browser: one loaded by Forge script, another is loaded from a webpack. This situation creates actual problems in the code when trying to use THREE types.

Comment: [Bryan Huang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1611132/bryan-huang) is it possible that you could you take a look at this?

Comment: Are you sure that installing `@types/three` installs the actual three.js library as well? That seems strange.

Comment: Without knowing too much about Angular 9 and its build system, the general situation is this: Forge Viewer includes three.js (version R71), and the library is automatically available through the `THREE` global variable. So the goal here is to somehow convince Angular to just assume that there will always be a `THREE` object in the global scope containing three.js library R71.

Comment: @PetrBroz I think the package is installed since after compilation it's loaded into a browser from a webpack. The source of this three.js version is visible in Chrome debugger as well as the other copy the comes with the viewer.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to avoid a compiler error when `THREE` objects are referenced in code without installing `@types/three`. In the TS file where something form THREE is referenced, for example a `THREE.Vector4`, instead of importing THREE from a module insert a "fake" declaration

```
declare var THREE: any;
```

The positive outcomes are:

1. No compilation error;
2. No second copy of three.js loaded from a webpack

A negative outcome is losing a TypeScript intellisense in VS Code but it could be mitigated by temporarily installing the `@types/three`, developing and testing the code and then removing `@types/three`.